# Зависание VPS с Fedora на arm7

Tags: linux, arm

Взял сервер на https://www.scaleway.com, arm7 с Fedora. Собрал свой проект: C++, многопоточность, критические секции, множественные вызовы malloc()/free(), множество сетевых запросов. Проект работает под Windows и Linux(32, 64) без проблем.

После запуска основного многопоточного алгоритма программы все четыре ядра загрузились на 100%, начала расти память. После остановки программы тенденция не прекратилась, память росла дальше, процессор так же загружен. Перестали запускаться программы, машина перестала отвечать по сети.

При уменьшении потоков и задач программа уже кое как работает, память так же растет, ядра загружаются на 100%. При убийстве процесса память освобождается не сразу, как и нагрузка на процессор.

В чем может быть причина такой низкой скорости. Или это арм "настолько" медленный?
Куда используется память? Два гига утекли за 10 минут.

Впервые сталкиваюсь c арм. Честно говоря ожидал большего. Проект нормально работает на самых дешевых VPS. У арм есть какие-то особенности, которые следует учитывать при разработке программ?

Comment: раз память течет - нужно смотреть глубже, например valgrind'ом. Вполне возможно, что у Вас есть платформеннозависимые участки кода и как раз для арма они написаны неверно. 

То, что процессор загружен под завязку - это нормально - я же так понимаю, у Вас числодробилка. Она хорошо загрузила все, и для других процессов просто не осталось свободного места.